# Prevent "Pattern not found" error in autocompletition (i_Ctrl-N)

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

I use the following mapping for `<Tab>`:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.')[col('.') - 2] =~ '\w' ? "<C-N>" : "<Tab>"
```

It works well except that if I want to insert a tab and the previous word is not matched, `i_Ctrl-N` returns the `Pattern not found` error and I have to insert a space manually and then I can insert a tab.

This is quite annoying.
I know I can use `pumvisible` to detect if completion pop-up is visible, but how can I evaluate the return value of `i_Ctrl-N`?